# glyphicon for facebook not showing up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I want to use the glyphicon for facebook, but how do I do that? I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facebook"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

But nothing shows up.

I also downloaded the free glyphicons, which include facebook, but I don't know how to include them.

EDIT - right now I'm using free glyphicons from the http://glyphicons.com/ site and just using them in an img tag.

Answer (score 3):

`glyphicon-facebook` is not a native Bootstrap icon, but you are calling it as though it is one.

See all bootstrap icons at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

You can use a facebook icon from a different library, like **[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)**. In Font Awesome, you would call the Facebook icon like so:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

Comment: I should say I'm using this within Bootstrap's navbar component, and the font awesome icons don't seem to be working there.

Comment: You should load the icon source before loading any header or body content.

Comment: Read the documentation - instructions here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to give this way:

```
<a href="" class="social facebook"
   data-name="facebook" data-type=""
   data-prefix="social" data-utf="E031"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library:

http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/

Download this file: [link](https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons/blob/master/css/bootstrap.icon-large.min.css)
include it in your page, then use it.

Example from there:

```
<li><i class="icon-large icon-facebook"></i> icon-facebook</li>

<ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl" ><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I download this zip file, how do I include it in my document?

Comment: Download this file: link include it in your page, then use it.

Comment: I downloaded it into c:\inetpub\wwwroot and called it "glyphs.css". I included it in my header as a css file. I went into the code and changed the glyphs.css code and changed the background image url to background-image:url("http://localhost/bootstrap-glyphicons-master/img/glyphicons.png"). But nothing is still happening.

Comment: You don't have the png, you have to download that too

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome should work for your needs (as mentioned). It sounds like you haven't loaded the Font Awesome CSS source, to do so this information will go in the  area of your document:

```
<link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Once the above is called, you should then be able to call the FB icon like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

You don't need to download any image files or CSS files to do this. You can take a look at a simple site I launched recently that uses Font Aweswome, if it helps you out:

http://1574buchertroad.com/